# What are the blank files in my Home Folder of macOS?

Tags: macos

[image]

[image]
[image: <code>ls -la</code> output]

file names: /build /el_capitan /optional /recommended /yosemite etc
All the files are created at the day I opened my mac for the first time (iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015))

Comment: That is very odd. How big are the files and if you open one in a text editor what is in them?

Comment: Yes, they are zero byte files. They can be opened in a text editor. They are all blank in a text editor. and in the Terminal with `cd ~/` `file :/mavericks` it comes `:mavericks: empty`

Comment: In my opinion this is some remnant of an older homebrew bottle (or something similar like a configure file) which typically contains the strings *:build :el_capitan :optional :recommended :yosemite etc.*.The : is interpreted as / in the Finder/HFS+. Check/repair your file system!

Comment: `ls -la` results in the image  [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKO3.png

Comment: The homebrew bottle probably is/was an older Macvim/vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like zero byte files created by an error of some sort. A good culprit is a script that has a path variable that usually points somewhere else and doesn't catch that the parameter or variable is blank - so your home folder (the current working) directory gets spammed.

I'd be slightly concerned since it's creating these wrong - what else is going wrong in that script? Deleting wrong files, or worse?

I'd be interested to see what the detailed information is for them. You can get this information using Finder list view, or via Terminal with `ls -la`. Whilst you're in Terminal, you could also do `file "/mavericks"` and see what that comes back with - it identifies the file type by its contents.

Did you buy your Mac brand new or previously used?

Comment: 1. Yes, they are zero byte files. 2. `ls -la` outputs: the file name ':optional'. `file : mavericks `  outputs  :mavericks: empty 3. I bought my Mac brand new.

Comment: `ls -la` results: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKO3.png

Answer (score 0):

Check the root directory on your hard drive (Go > Computer) to see if you have any more files like that floating around.

If those are the only ones, just delete them. They aren't doing anything and appear to be flotsam from the installation process. If your hard drive is littered with similar files, then reinstall the OS from scratch.